# Annotate bars with values on Pandas bar plots for subplots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to annotate the bars in a pandas barplot. My following Code works for a single plot without subplots but unfortunately not for subplots.

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(2),'B':np.random.rand(2)},index=['2018-10-30 12:00:00','2018-10-30 12:15:00',] )         
print(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot.bar(ax=ax, title='My Barplots',subplots = False, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

The moment I change the "subplots = False" to "subplots = True" the annotations are not showing anymore.

Can anyone help on how to make this work with subplots?

Comment: `ax` needs to be the subplot where you want the annotations to be. `df.plot` returns an array of those subplots, so you need to do it for each of them.

Comment: `UserWarning: To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared`

Comment: Thanks  ImportanceOfBeingErnest and Quang Hoang you lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments. Now I have found the solution.

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(2),'B':np.random.rand(2)},index=['2018-10-30 12:00:00','2018-10-30 12:15:00',] )         
print(df)

axes = df.plot.bar( title='My Barplots',subplots = True, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axes:
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(str(round(p.get_height(),2)), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

I have done a second Loop over the axes of the figure now. This works.

[image]